# Good open source Android GPS apps showing topographic lines and remote roads in the US?

Tags: united-states, gps, cell-phones

Are there any good open-source Android GPS apps that show topographic contour lines and remote roads, with labels for both? Something OpenStreetMap-based would be ideal, so I can add missing roads.

I'm specifically looking for open-source apps, not just no-cost apps. I'm okay with paying as long as the app is open source, although paid open-source apps are rare.

Comment: Have you considered any in particular? For example, OsmAnd is open source, openstreetmap based, and has a countour line layer.

Comment: @GregHewgill thanks for the suggestion! I'll try it.

Comment: Despite the different activity, the answers will probably be the same as the recent discussion on mapping for via ferrata. That would be worth a look

Comment: [This question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/28391/2529)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is a list](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android) of Andoid apps (propiretary and free) that provide navigation with OSM. Open Source?  Open-source code or displays open-source data?

[Avenza PDF Maps](https://www.avenzamaps.com/mobile-maps?campaignid=10221828697&adgroupid=102940455500&adid=453083166133&gclid=CjwKCAjw9NeXBhAMEiwAbaY4lkJS9ovntxK6QrIVOoK1IpFyYK61CXWA2zUdTDTAUgpECr9WxtxxxBoCc_wQAvD_BwE) offers a free account that allows you to display downloaded maps.  In the free account you have three maps active at a time.  You can download free USGS topographic maps from the [Avenza map store](https://www.avenzamaps.com/maps/search.html?campaignid=10221828697&adgroupid=102940455500&adid=453083166133&gclid=CjwKCAjw9NeXBhAMEiwAbaY4ll4Ol3rus5OOB0QMUV4n1Ieg3X4Cw5s5BNNiXbaIvPuJ8tMJB-he4BoCmFkQAvD_BwE&query=&location_mode=user_input&location=&sort=relevance&price_max=&is_bundle=0&page=-1&debug=&current_map_id=), or [download them from the USA government](https://ngmdb.usgs.gov/topoview/viewer/#4/40.01/-100.06) for free. There are hosts of paid map content on the Avenza map store but you can filter by price and location and quickly find what you need. An Avenza Pro account allows you to have more than three active maps but with the free version you can store any number of maps on your devices and just remove the unneeded maps and replace them with the needed maps in the app.

Avenza will display your chosen downloaded maps without requiring a cellular connection (although location services will deplete your battery).  You can create waypoints as KML files and download/display the KML at home using Google Earth.

Comment: I was referring to open-source software, but thank you for the suggestion! I'll look at the free USGS topo map downloads.

Comment: Avenza has Forest Service Motor Vehicle Use Maps available for free, and they indicate your position properly on them (and I have more than 3 on my free account). Heck, the Forest Service even points you to them. I still prefer other (paid) products. The cost of them are pretty small compared with, say, ammunition for hunting.

Comment: @JonCuster cost isn't my concern; I wouldn't use a no-cost closed source app if I could avoid it, and I would be willing to pay for an open-source app (within reason, of course, and it's unlikely that this will happen because the vast majority of open-source software is no-cost.)

Answer (score 2):

[Oruxmaps](https://oruxmaps.com/cs/en/) is not unfortunately not open source, but it plays well with open map formats and can display many types of online and offline maps, including topographic maps. It can be used in a completely offline non-cloud mode, saving tracks etc. locally.
Oruxmaps can directly import USGS pdf maps.
It can also use DEM elevation data to for hillshading.
Overall a great program I have been using for years for offline mapping

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is somewhat roundabout, but it provides almost exactly what you're looking for by enabling the use of open and free WMS data from various sources.

[Peakbagger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mountainside.peakbagger&hl=fr_CA&gl=US) is an app that links with the peakbagger.com mountain database. These are aimed at climbers and mountaineers, but it has several abilities that can be used in other fields:

- Choice of around 10 basemaps, several of which are topographical data
- Ability to download map data from those basemaps around peaks for offline use
- Ability to record GPX tracks and waypoints
- The website and app are not open source in the sense that you can't obtain the source code and modify it. They are free of any charge though. Any licensing that was required to use the WMS basemaps is paid and handled by the website owner or the app owner (two different people). To offset this, there are ads, which can be removed for logged in users.

You can create an account on the website to log ascents and hikes, I can't remember if the app requires you to link your account before you can use it.

I mainly use that app for logging my ascents while on extended trips, but I also have used it to replace my handheld GPS on day-hikes.

The main drawback is that you can't do routing or trip planning, only show basemaps, saved tracks, and peaks in the database.